# Injecting user built component in play module

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using using pac4j for security along with play framework. In pac4j, authorizers needs to be created for authorization. This I'm doing in a module which extends **AbstractModule**. For this, I need to call my custom service which will get Authorizer from DB.

I've bound all the classes in another module using guice. All classes are bound before security module is invoked. I've injected my custom service in the module but it always comes as null.

Is there any way to inject my custom service is module?

Comment: You want to use a service *inside* the module? If so, you're probably on the wrong path, since modules are rather a description of your dependencies rather than a place to call services.

Comment: Yeah, I think I may have taken a wrong path here. I am trying to set up authorizers dynamically in a module and needed to call a service for that.

Comment: You might want to move that part to the actual code.